# backbone.layoutmanager produces error messages "set `View#manage` property with selector '' to `true`"

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-layout-manager

I asked this question elsewhere. But I would ask it here too in case who knows the answer.

I recently wrote a simple web app. It has two views in total, and users should be able to go back and forward between the two views. It seems nature to me that setView method can the job of changing the app view. It works all good when switching from Index view to Show view by clicking a link. However, it cannot go back to Index view when I click a link. It just pops up this error message "Please set View#manage property with selector '' to true". Since the old view objects should have been destroy when switching to another view, why it would have this error unless it's not working as I thought it would be.

Below is a snippet of my coffeescript code.
        MyApp.Routers.Home = Backbone.Router.extend(
          routes:
            'books' : 'showBooksIndex'
            'books/:id' : 'showBook'

```
      initialize: (options) ->
        @buildLayout()

      buildLayout: ->
        @layout = app.useLayout("main")

      showBooksIndex: ->
        @cleanLayout()
        @books = new MyApp.Collections.Book();
        @viewIndex = new MyApp.Views.BooksIndex(
            collection: @books;
        )
        @layout.setView('#app', @viewIndex)

      showBook: (id) ->
        @cleanLayout()
        @book = new MyApp.Models.Book id: id
        @view = new MyApp.Views.BookShow model: @book
        @layout.setView('#app', @view)

      cleanLayout: ->
        appView = @layout.getView('#app')
        if appView
          appView.remove()

    MyApp.Views.BookShow = Backbone.View.extend(
      id: "book-show"
      className: "book-card"
      manage: true
      template: JST['templates/books/show']
      initialize: ->
        @model = @options.model
        _this = @
        @model.fetch(
          success: (model, resp)->
            _this.render();
        )
```

MyApp.Views.BooksIndex is has similar code to BookShow view.

Caching the views is probably a solution too. This approach will work around this issue because recreation of view objects is avoided. But since my app have lots of photos, I would prefer to fetch data from server every time the app view changes. I am not sure if it is the right way to go. Thanks in advance for sharing your insights.

Comment: Do you set LayoutManager globally to `manage:true`? Or do you set it up only on a few ones?

Comment: Yes, I set that in Backbone.LayoutManager.configure. It only emit this error when switching back to the first view from the second.